# How to add an existing QGSVectorLayer to QGIS project?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I know I can pull a vector file into my current project using:

```
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(r"S:/Data/Natural_Earth_quick_start/110m_cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp", "admin", "ogr")
```

But if I create my layer using something like:

```
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(r"S:/Data/Natural_Earth_quick_start/110m_cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp", "admin", "ogr")
```

and then I do some processing on `vlayer` how do I then add it to the current project or map layers list?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "processing"? Editing the layer such as modifying features, running a tool from the processing toolbox etc? Or do you mean something like: `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)`?

Comment: that is the correct answer

Comment: Any sort of process that changes the layer features

Comment: You can see in the PyQGIS cookbook how to add a `QgsVectorLayer` to the project https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#qgsproject-instance

Comment: @etrimaille - thanks, I spotted that soon after I got the answer here :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To add an existing single layer:

  ```
  vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("some/path/to/shapefile.shp", "admin", "ogr")
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
  ```

---

- To add existing multiple layers:

  ```
  vlayer1 = QgsVectorLayer("some/path/to/shapefile1.shp", "admin1", "ogr")
  vlayer2 = QgsVectorLayer("some/path/to/shapefile2.shp", "admin2", "ogr")
  layers = [vlayer1 , vlayer2]
  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layers)
  ```